# What will happen to the electrical grid?

Tags: power-supply

I would like to know:

1. What happens if a major amount of generating capacity trips offline?
2. What happens if an extremely large load is instantly added online to the grid?

what will happen to the electrical network?

Comment: Both have happened, do a search.

Comment: A new development in grids is the addition of large battery banks. These can help prevent collapse in both cases by reacting very quickly. After a few minutes, the conventional generators can adjust. I think if you are going to operate a really large load, you would coordinate with the utility company. But there could still be unplanned load changes, I am sure.

Answer (score 2):

Both events lead to the power generation and load imbalance. The system will experience two different processes going either in sequence or simultaneously.

First is frequency drop. The system will try to recover by increasing power generation. If it is not enough, some load will be tripped either manually or by automatic load shedding.

Second is increase of power flows between system parts. This may cause transient or small signal stability problems as well as thermal overload of the power transmission lines. A consequence is line tripping and separation of the power system to several asyncrounous parts.

If system has splitted into parts, apply this answer recursively to each of them.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a lot of detail, see https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/855767/e3c-gb-power-disruption-9-august-2019-final-report.pdf

> On Friday 9 August 2019, over 1 million customers were affected by a major power
> disruption that occurred across England and Wales and some parts of Scotland4. Though the
> power disconnection itself was relatively short lived – all customers were restored within 45
> minutes - the knock-on impacts to other services were significant

> The initial findings from the ESO’s Technical Report5 of 6 September show that the incident is
> thought to have been caused by a lightning strike to an overhead transmission line and the
> near simultaneous loss of a number of generators at approximately the same time. The system
> response (back-up generation) held by the ESO at the time of the incident was just over
> 1,000MW. However, the total generation lost from the affected power stations and a number of
> smaller generators, as part of the initial event, was at least 2,000MW, greater than the
> response held. This loss caused the system frequency to drop below the statutory limit of
> 49.5Hz to 48.8Hz.

> Once the frequency of the system dropped to 48.8Hz, stage one (of nine) of the automatic
> protection system known as Low Frequency Demand Disconnection (LFDD) was triggered,
> which had the effect of disconnecting approximately 900MW of demand (equating to over 1
> million customers), to arrest the fall in frequency.

So: the answer is that this causes a fall in *frequency*, as the remaining spinning generators are unable to keep up, and that results in automatic protection systems disconnecting users until the system stabilizes.

It's possible that cascade failures occur. This was one such case: the lightning strike trips a generator, the local fluctuation triggers a software bug in a wind farm which *also* fails, and so on.

Comment: And new non-spinning generators like battery storage systems are designed to mimic spinning generators, increasing their output (up to their max) as the frequency falls.

Answer (score 0):

If a major part of the generating capacity trips off the other parts try to output more if they can and they are programmed to do so. To protect themselves against overloading the other generating stations may see it's best to disconnect itself. Or if a company governs a larger area than just a single power station it may only disconnect that area from the rest of the grid to stay functional for smaller circuit.

The whole electricity production can collapse like a house of cards. Here and there can stay still operating islands where everything works, but with no connection to the rest of the grid.

A big sudden load peak can start the collapse. Generating such peak is possible by using modern communication for example by giving to millions of people a good reason to turn all lights on approximately at the same time. A radical sudden change in the weather can cause the same in countries where electric heating and cooling is popular.

Answer (score -1):

it all depends on how "massive."  (it's a matter of energy not mass)  Usually the grid is so much more "massive" that it only suffers a minor drop in voltage which kicks off remedial efforts to increase it again usually via turning on another power source such as a gas generator or even a battery (which tends to be twofold since it also stops charging the battery).  This is usually fast enough that the grid recovers without falling out of spec.

If something were so large a load that the grid risks falling out of spec, the grid is likely to cut off less critical lines close to the load (of which that load is likely one), allowing it to keep at least higher priority lines within spec.